# Understanding writeDataToPipe

Tags: java, android, design-patterns

I found this code snippet in latest Android notepad tutorial [link](http://developer.android.com/training/notepad/index.html) which is using contentprovider and implementing PipeDataWriter.

The interface has its method writeDataToPipe which they implemented like this:

```
@Override
public void writeDataToPipe(ParcelFileDescriptor output, Uri uri, String mimeType, Bundle opts, Cursor c) {
    // We currently only support conversion-to-text from a single note entry,
    // so no need for cursor data type checking here.
    FileOutputStream fout = new FileOutputStream(output.getFileDescriptor());
    PrintWriter pw = null;
    try {
        pw = new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(fout, "UTF-8"));
        pw.println(c.getString(READ_NOTE_TITLE_INDEX));
        pw.println("");
        pw.println(c.getString(READ_NOTE_NOTE_INDEX));
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        Log.w(TAG, "Ooops", e);
    } finally {
        c.close();
        if (pw != null) {
            pw.flush();
        }
        try {
            fout.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
        }
    }
}
```

My doubt is that why specifically they are using PipeDataWriter?

Is that some kind of design pattern?

I found no other source where it has been used. Why so?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> why specifically they are using PipeDataWriter?

They are using `openPipeHelper()` in their implementation of `openTypedAssetFile()`. `openPipeHelper()` takes a `PipeDataWriter` as a parameter. In their case, they implemented `PipeDataWriter` on the `NotePadProvider` itself, and therefore need to implement `openPipeHelper()` to fulfill the contract required by the `PipeDataWriter` interface.

`PipeDataWriter` and `openPipeHelper()` are new to API Level 11. Previously, you had to roll your own solution for forking a thread to return the contents of a file.